# Working with hostapd

Tags: wireless-access-point, hostapd

I have installed hostapd in my Ubuntu 14.04 and I am relatively new to this application. In the coming days I will be doing some minor changes in the hostapd codebase and testing it around. This may affect the way hostapd works and impact the underlying Wi-Fi operations and I don't want my Wi-Fi connection in Ubuntu to be affected. Would anyone recommend how should I go about working with hostpd. Is there any safe method through which I can play around hostapd code base without my Wi-Fi connection getting affected. Any inputs would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you make changes in the codebase of hostapd? Hostapd is maintained very well and works pretty good. Hostapd is an application to set up a software AP as you obviously know. It only affects the network adapter you specify in the configuration file of hostapd and nothing else. Only when you activate hostapd this comes into play.

Basically you can change whatever you want and if hostapd malfunctions just stop it and everything is as it was before. I recommend you to start and stop hostapd from the terminal during your experiments.

Of course you need to use it with a second network adapter and not the one you are using for your regular network connection.